# How do you make a reference from all page numbers to the ToC?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Hey fellow LaTeX users.

Is there any way to make the page numbers in a document `hyperref`back to the header of the TOC?

It would be very useful in my document so I quickly could jump back and forth to the ToC.

Comment: Where on the ToC page would you want to jump to? The header, the first "real" line, the sectional entry closest to the referring page, or something else?

Comment: edited my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a `\label` just before `\tableofcontents` which could be indexed and linked to by `hyperref`. Here’s a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% Set up the header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Put the link in the header
\fancyhead[RO]{This is a link to the~\hyperref[toc-contents]{\textbf{Table of Contents}}}

% This fills the document with dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\label{toc-contents}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

and the top of a page looks something like:

[image]

Clicking the bold text would take you to the table of contents.

Of course, you could use something other than `fancyhdr` to set up the link in the header if you have a different package that you prefer or are already using.

---

**ETA:** I should really have read the question more carefully. If you want the *page numbers* to link to the table of contents, then you replace the header/footer code above by

```
% Set up the header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Put the link in the footer
\fancyfoot[CO]{\hyperref[toc-contents]{\thepage}}
```

Comment: How do you make the page number appear to the right of the header instead of in the middle of the footer?

Comment: @Khaurum: Use `\fancyhead[RO]{\hyperref[toc-contents]{\thepage}}` instead of the `fancyfoot[…]{…}`.

Comment: @alexwlchan I have my TOC within a couple of `\newpage`, the links back to TOC actually link back to the first page instead of TOC. What do I need to change?

Comment: The solution proposed is not correct. It only works here because it puts the TOC as the first page of the document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600955/161015 as alternative.