# Hyperlink on pages to jump back to table of contents directs to the wrong place

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I tried the solution in [How do you make a reference from all page numbers to the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142743/how-do-you-make-a-reference-from-all-page-numbers-to-the-toc) to add a link to Table of Contents at each page number. The solution added the links at the page numbers, but directs to the first page of the document, not the Table of Contents.
The code I have used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hyperref[toc-contents]{\thepage}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Page 1 \newpage 
Page 2 \newpage

\label{toc-contents}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: make a *complete* example. How should we know what is in the rest of your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there are a couple of blank pages between the first page of the document and the table of contents. That's a template for a monograph doc.

Comment: sorry but without a compilable, complete example I can't help you.

Comment: Useful reference for [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  In particular, you might be able to add a `\section` or two, and use `lipsum`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the reply. Now the code is compilable.

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks for the reply. Now the code is compilable.

Comment: well the label is on page one, try with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{toc-contents}}` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: You could also try `\phantomsection` before `\tableofcontents`.  Although that might end on up the previous page.

Comment: i have tried both suggestions, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

To direct all the links to the TOC attach  the label to its title.

It is also necessary to redefine the `plain` style, used on the first page of the chapters.

**Notes.**

(1) The solution proposed in [how-do-you-make-a-reference-from-all-page-numbers-to-the-toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142743/how-do-you-make-a-reference-from-all-page-numbers-to-the-toc) is not correct. It only works because it puts the TOC as the first page of the document, as you  already discover.

(2) To test this solution put `\tableofcontents` just before `\end{document}` and compile twice. Now all links will send you to the page #5 (the last).

[image: b]

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% ***********************************************************   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\hyperref[toc-contents]\thepage} % all pages <<<  

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%redefine \pagestyle{plain} to add the link <<<
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyfoot[C]{\hyperref[toc-contents]\thepage} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}%
    
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Some title\label{toc-contents}} % label in TOC title<<<<
% ***********************************************************

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref} % last to load

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    Page 1 \newpage 
    Page 2 \newpage 
    
    \tableofcontents    
    \mainmatter
    \blinddocument
            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose i have to maintain the \label{toc-contents} before \tableofcontents. Still, the links direct to the first page.

Comment: @Stefani  Did you try the code of my answer? The link is to the title of TOC. Never goes to the first page.

Comment: I added your code into the doc template I have to use. The template has many other latex codes, maybe one of those is interfering.

Comment: @Stefani  To test put   `\tableofcontents `  before `\end{document}`  and compile twice.  All links will send you to the last page (#5).

Comment: @Stefani Remember to put  `hyperref` as the last package to load.